# how to run screen on gitlub runner

Tags: linux, bash, gitlab, screen

How I can run screen on gitlub runner?

Now I have this code:

```
stages: 
  - deploy

deploy-job:      
  stage: deploy  
  environment: production
  script:
    - screen -x test
    - echo "Deploying application..."
    - echo "Application successfully deployed."
```

but I get error message:

```
Must be connected to a terminal.
```

gitlab-runner has sudo access.

```
script /dev/null
```

doesn't work

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to do that ? You are working on a non interactive shell so not sure what's the added value of screen here

Comment: I wan't to run python project, but I run it without screen, I can't use console.